# Sml MI programming function number_in_month

Tags: functional-programming

I am newbie in ml programming,I have a homework to write function that takes a list of dates and a month and returns how many dates in the list are in the given month.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I'll give you a hint, that it involves recursion, checking 3 conditions, base case list is empty, #second member of the tuple is equal to the month passed in, and all other months.

`fun number_in_month(ds: (int*int*int) list, m: int) = ...`